# How to function return a selectbox with foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

I am writing some code for a plugin in joomla. I need to return a html select populated with a foreach with data from an array. I got stuch in commas.... Something like this, but populated with foreach:

```
return '<select id="'.$this->id.'" name="'.$this->name.'">'.
           '<option value="1" >New York</option>'.
           '<option value="2" >Chicago</option>'.
           '<option value="3" >San Francisco</option>'.
           '</select>';
```

Comment: You can't write a `foreach`?

Comment: I am still learning :)

Comment: Please improve the question - see stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a `foreach` loop is kinda simple:

```
$result = '<select id="'.$this->id.'" name="'.$this->name.'">';
foreach (array(1 => 'New York', 2 => 'Chicago') as $k => $v) {
    $result .= '<option value="' . $k .'" >' . $v . '</option>';
}
$result .= '</select>';
return $result;
```